# OpenSearch: Querying for cardinality of a field by bucket

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

Is there a way to query for the unique count of a field per terms aggregation bucket?

For example, assume I have an index called `cars` with documents like this:

```json
{
  "year": 2023,
  "make": "toyota",
  "model": "camry",
  "color": "red"
}
```

is there an aggregation that would allow me to query for the number of unique colors by year?

If I were to store the same information in a single Postgres table, I might use the following query for what I'm looking for:

```sql
SELECT year, COUNT(DISTINCT color)
FROM cars
GROUP BY year;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a nested aggregation was what I was looking for:

```
GET _search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs":{
    "docs_by_year": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "year",
        "size": 50
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique_colors": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "color"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```